# XSLT: Merge nodes, then sort

Tags: xslt

I have a XML like this:

```
<node id="1">
    <data alias="Show">ShowName1</data>
    <data alias="Dates">21/04/2009,23/04/2009,27/04/2009,</data>
</node>

<node id="2">
    <data alias="Show">ShowName2</data>
    <data alias="Dates">22/04/2009,25/04/2009,29/04/2009,</data>
</node>
```

It has X number of nodes, each with a name of a show, and a string of comma separated show dates.
I can tokenize the show dates, but I want to make a sorted list with all show dates for all shows, sorted by dates. Like this:

```
<shows>
    <show>
        <name>ShowName1</name>
        <date>21/04/2009</date>
    </show>
    <show>
        <name>ShowName2</name>
        <date>22/04/2009</date>
    </show>
    <show>
        <name>ShowName1</name>
        <date>23/04/2009</date>
    </show>
    <show>
        <name>ShowName2</name>
        <date>25/04/2009</date>
    </show>
    <show>
        <name>ShowName1</name>
        <date>27/04/2009</date>
    </show>
    <show>
        <name>ShowName2</name>
        <date>29/04/2009</date>
    </show>
</shows>
```

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this using only **one** transform process would require your newly created show elements to be seen as a **node-set** so the templates can use the internal **xsl:sort** mechanics.  The [XSL Transformations (XSLT) Version 1.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt) does not have a method to turn self created elements into a node set.  However, the [MSXML parser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hz88kef0(VS.71).aspx) (3.0 or greater) does have an extension to provide that functionality.  Also, there's an [exslt extension](http://www.exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html) that I think some newer versions of Firefox support that will allow this dynamic swap of a variable to a node-set.  But anyways, here's a stylesheet that works properly using the MSXML parser.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="shows">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//data[@alias='Dates']"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <shows>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="msxsl:node-set($shows)//show">
        <xsl:sort select="substring(date, 7, 4)"/><!-- year -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(date, 4, 2)"/><!-- month -->
        <xsl:sort select="substring(date, 1, 2)"/><!-- day -->
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </shows>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="show">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data[@alias='Dates']">
    <xsl:call-template name="eachDate">
      <xsl:with-param name="node" select=".."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="dates" select="."/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="eachDate">
    <xsl:param name="node" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="dates" select="''"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($dates)">
      <show>
        <name><xsl:value-of select="$node/data[@alias='Show']/text()"/></name>
        <date><xsl:value-of select="substring-before($dates, ',')"/></date>
      </show>
      <xsl:call-template name="eachDate">
        <xsl:with-param name="node" select="$node"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="dates" select="substring-after($dates, ',')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This gets the date sorting wrong. You need to sort by individual dates, *and* they are not sort-friendly "DDMMYYYY", so they must be tokenized as well, and turned to "YYYYMMDD" before sorting.

Comment: good catch, it worked plenty well for the supplied small amount of data.
all you need to do is sort by substring(data, 7, 4), etc. updated my xsl:sort to show what I mean. no need to tokenize, or disrupt the text value at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot. You guys are the best! Just what I needed, and problem solved  (and my apologies to Dimitre for not providing a well-formed XML, won't happen again :) )

Answer (score 1):

Since the input XML is in a rather bad shape, we must jump through some hoops to get what you want.

As Mister Lucky already outlined in his answer, we must transform the document into a more useful temporary form first. The more useful temporary form would then be turned back into a node-set by an extension function, and processed again to produce the desired result.

In my answer I'll use a modified identity transform to achieve the following temporary form:

```
<root>
  <node id="1">
    <data alias="Show">ShowName1</data>
    <data alias="Dates">
      <date sort="20090421">21/04/2009</date>
      <date sort="20090423">23/04/2009</date>
      <date sort="20090427">27/04/2009</date>
    </data>
  </node>
  <node id="2">
    <data alias="Show">ShowName2</data>
    <data alias="Dates">
      <date sort="20090422">22/04/2009</date>
      <date sort="20090425">25/04/2009</date>
      <date sort="20090429">29/04/2009</date>
    </data>
  </node>
</root>
```

With this input, sorting is straightforward, using the `@sort` attribute of the `<date>` elements.

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl "
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- prepare our temporary form (a "result tree fragment") -->
    <xsl:variable name="rtf">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="rtf" />
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- transform the result tree fragment back to a node-set -->
    <xsl:variable name="doc" select="msxsl:node-set($rtf)" />

    <!-- transform the temporary node-set, sorted by date -->
    <shows>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$doc//date">
        <xsl:sort select="@sort" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </shows>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="date">
    <show show_id="{ancestor::node/@id}">
      <name><xsl:value-of select="../../data[@alias='Show'][1]/text()" /></name>
      <date><xsl:value-of select="." /></date>
    </show>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- all following templates are for producing the temporary form only -->

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="rtf">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="rtf" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="data[@alias='Dates']" mode="rtf">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- copy all attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" mode="rtf" />
      <!-- this produces the <date> elements -->
      <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-datelist" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize-datelist">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="." />
    <xsl:param name="delim" select="','" />

    <xsl:variable name="temp" select="concat($input, $delim)" />
    <xsl:variable name="head" select="substring-before($temp, $delim)" />
    <xsl:variable name="tail" select="substring-after($input, $delim)" />

    <xsl:if test="$head != ''">
      <date>
        <!-- this produces the @sort attribute -->
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-date">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$head" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:value-of select="$head" />
      </date>
      <xsl:if test="$tail != ''" >
        <xsl:call-template name="tokenize-datelist">
          <xsl:with-param name="input" select="$tail" />
          <xsl:with-param name="delim" select="$delim" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="tokenize-date">
    <xsl:param name="input" select="''" />
    <xsl:param name="delim" select="'/'" />

    <xsl:variable name="dd" select="substring-before($input, $delim)" />
    <xsl:variable name="my" select="substring-after($input, $delim)" />
    <xsl:variable name="mm" select="substring-before($my, $delim)" />
    <xsl:variable name="yy" select="substring-after($my, $delim)" />

    <xsl:attribute name="sort">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat($yy, $mm, $dd)" />
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When this is run through msxsl.exe, an XSLT 1.0 processor, the following output is produced:

```
<shows>
  <show show_id="1">
    <name>ShowName1</name>
    <date>21/04/2009</date>
  </show>
  <show show_id="2">
    <name>ShowName2</name>
    <date>22/04/2009</date>
  </show>
  <show show_id="1">
    <name>ShowName1</name>
    <date>23/04/2009</date>
  </show>
  <show show_id="2">
    <name>ShowName2</name>
    <date>25/04/2009</date>
  </show>
  <show show_id="1">
    <name>ShowName1</name>
    <date>27/04/2009</date>
  </show>
  <show show_id="2">
    <name>ShowName2</name>
    <date>29/04/2009</date>
  </show>
</shows>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I. AN XSLT 1.0 solution using FXSL 1.x**

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"
 exclude-result-prefixes="ext"
>
   <xsl:import href="strSplit-to-Words.xsl"/>

   <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:variable name="vDates">
        <xsl:for-each select="node">
            <nodeData name="{data[@alias = 'Show']}">
                 <xsl:call-template name="str-split-to-words">
                  <xsl:with-param name="pStr" select="data[@alias = 'Dates']"/>
                  <xsl:with-param name="pDelimiters"
                                  select="','"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </nodeData>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="ext:node-set($vDates)/*/*[text()]">
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="substring(.,7)"/>
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="substring(.,4,2)"/>
        <xsl:sort data-type="number" select="substring(.,1,2)"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="word">
      <show>
        <name>
          <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
        </name>
          <date>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </date>
      </show>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided "XML document", corrected to be well-formed** (When will you, people, learn to provide a well-formed XML document? Is it *that* difficult?):

```
<t>
    <node id="1">
        <data alias="Show">ShowName1</data>
        <data alias="Dates">21/04/2009,23/04/2009,27/04/2009,</data>
    </node>
    <node id="2">
        <data alias="Show">ShowName2</data>
        <data alias="Dates">22/04/2009,25/04/2009,29/04/2009,</data>
    </node>
</t>
```

**produces the wanted result**:

```
<show>
   <name>ShowName1</name>
   <date>21/04/2009</date>
</show>
<show>
   <name>ShowName2</name>
   <date>22/04/2009</date>
</show>
<show>
   <name>ShowName1</name>
   <date>23/04/2009</date>
</show>
<show>
   <name>ShowName2</name>
   <date>25/04/2009</date>
</show>
<show>
   <name>ShowName1</name>
   <date>27/04/2009</date>
</show>
<show>
   <name>ShowName2</name>
   <date>29/04/2009</date>
</show>
```

**II. One possible XSLT 2.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">

     <xsl:variable name="vAllData" as="xs:string+">
          <xsl:for-each select="node">
            <xsl:variable name="vName" select="data[@alias='Show']"/>

              <xsl:for-each select=
                "tokenize(data[@alias='Dates'], ',')[.]">

                <xsl:value-of select="concat($vName, '+',.)"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>

         <xsl:for-each select="$vAllData">
           <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
            "substring(substring-after(.,'+'),7)"/>
           <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
            "substring(substring-after(.,'+'),4,2)"/>
           <xsl:sort data-type="number" select=
            "substring(substring-after(.,'+'),1,2)"/>

           <show>
             <name>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(.,'+')"/>
             </name>
             <date>
               <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(.,'+')"/>
             </date>
           </show>
       </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above XSLT 2.0 transformation is applied on the same document, the same correct result is produced**.